# Use docker-compose to execute a script right before the container is stopped

Tags: docker-compose

Let's say I want to execute a cleanup script whenever container termination is triggered. How do I go about this using docker-compose?

This could be handy to automatically back up the files, databases, etc for the dev container.

Answer (score 4):

`docker` containers are meant to be [ephemeral](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#create-ephemeral-containers):

> By "ephemeral", we mean that the container can be stopped and destroyed, then rebuilt and replaced with an absolute minimum set up and configuration.

Building upon this concept `docker` itself does not offer anything to hook into the shutdown process. `docker-compose` is built on top of `docker` and also does not add such functionality.

Maybe you can rethink your problem *the `docker` way* to better fit the intended use of `docker`. Without further context it is hard to say what could be a good solution but maybe one of the following approaches helps you out:

- [`docker stop`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/stop/) sends a `SIGTERM` signal to the main process in the container. You could use a custom entrypoint or supervisor process that would trigger the appropriate actions on a `SIGTERM`. This approach requires custom containers. With the [`stop_signal` attribute](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#stop_signal) you can also configure a custom signa to be sent in your `docker-compose.yml`
- if you just want to persist data files from the containers just [configuring the right `volumes`](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/05_persisting_data/) might be enough
- you could use [`docker events`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/events/) to listen and act upon any types of events emitted by the `docker daemon`

Comment: Thanks! I saw similar comments on SO while hunting for a solution. I understand the ephemeral part, this is exactly why I would like to backup things as and when I take down the container. My thinking was, hey if docker can help me setup services and containers, could there be an obvious solution to backup as part of the shutdown sequence.

Comment: @AneeshPanoli What solution, if any, did you find for this?